# how to use preg_match for whitelisting a string?

Tags: php

i want to check a string contains unwanted character or not. 
I want to allow only a string which will contains only @ _ a-z . 
I want if the string contains anything except this character will give me a false output. i want to check a string which will return true if the string doesn't contains my expected characters.

I tried to use preg_match to do this. But unable to do this. I think preg_match isnot the function i need for this. Please suggest me the best way to reach my desire goal.

```
$text='Hel&o';
if(!preg_match("/.@_[a-zA-Z0-9]/", $text) ){
return false;
}else {
return true;
}
```

Comment: That's a good example of how *not* to validate an email address.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_validate_email.asp

Comment: why not use `filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` Check [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)

Comment: I am trying to check a string with whitelist approach. Please help me to check a string contains nonwhitelisted charecters or not.

Comment: filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) doesnot find errors on su&@kk.net email.

Comment: @wind that's because su&@kk.net is a valid email address according to RFC 2822: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822

Comment: I want my own solution. I want to skip any text string contains &. Its not about email validation. Its about my own whitelisting a string.

Comment: I would suggest match for unwanted chars `[^@_.A-Za-z0-9]`

Comment: yes bansi i want to know how to check a string contains non expected charecters. I want to approach in whitelisting way. not blacklisting way.

Comment: try `return !preg_match("/[^\.@_a-zA-Z0-9]/", $text) );`

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using preg_match and not filter_var, then try this:

`/^[a-zA-Z0-9.@_]+$/`

Edited to add what CD001 commented.

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/hSI

Comment: Probably want a `+` rather than a `*` (can't imagine the OP wants an empty string to match, though you never know) but that does what's requested... oh, and `^...$` to ensure nothing sneaks in.

Comment: @CD001 well, who knows. As long as it's white listed :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've created a little function to filter a string:

```
function str_whitelist($string, $whitelist, $strict = false) {
    $whitelist = str_split((!$strict ? strtolower($whitelist) : $whitelist));
    $stringsplit = str_split($string);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($stringsplit); $i++) {
        $string = !in_array((!$strict ? strtolower($stringsplit[$i]) : $stringsplit[$i]), $whitelist, $strict) ? str_replace($stringsplit[$i], '', $string) : $string;
    }

    return $string;
}
```

Usage:

```
str_whitelist("Hello123", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ") // Output -> Hello
```